# Why does ioredis client timeout when keep-alive is enabled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, azure-redis-cache, ioredis

I have been getting the following error, when my script stays idle for sometime. I cannot understand the reason for this.

```
    error: [ioredis] Unhandled error event: 
error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) 
error: [ioredis] Unhandled error event
error: Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
```

I initialize my redis client as :

```
let redis = require("ioredis");
redis = Promise.promisifyAll(redis);

const redis = new redis({
   host: "my hostname",
   port: 6379,
   password: "some password"
});
```

and I am using [ioredis client](https://github.com/luin/ioredis).

Does anyone know the reason for this? The keep-alive is already enabled by default as suggested here https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/API.md

I want the client to never timeout and reconnect if the timeout occurs. I am using Redis service by azure.

Comment: Same issue happens to me with _ioredis_ lib and docker image of _redis_. Also added `commandTimeout` option, receiving `commandTimeout`s for about 10 mins, and only then rceiving ETIMEDOUT from connection

Answer (score 0):

We have an entire document that covers this topic: [Troubleshoot Azure Cache for Redis timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-troubleshoot-timeouts)

If using the StackExchange.Redis Client the best practice of using the following pattern is suggested:

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("cachename.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=...");
});
public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
   {
get
{
return lazyConnection.Value;
}
}
```

In the case of ioredis, you can set a client property: `[options.lazyConnect]`

You will also want to look at any retry methods available with your client. I hope this helps.